# JFrame Components not being displayed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jmenubar

I am attempting to add components to a JFrame but the only thing being displayed is my *ImageIcon* when I run GameMenu.java. I have instantiated *setVisible();* specifically **after** I have set my frame or added components to the panels or menubars. So I'm unsure as to why no components are showing up. I think it may have something to do with my formatting or main method.

Here are my two classes:

**GameMenu.java:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class GameMenu{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrameCaller obj = new FrameCaller();
    }

}

class FrameCaller extends JFrame {

    public FrameCaller(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("logo.png")));
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu m1 = new JMenu("Game List");
            JMenu m2 = new JMenu("Help");
            JMenu m3 = new JMenu("Stats");
                mb.add(m1);
                mb.add(m2);
                mb.add(m3);
        JMenuItem showRulesButton = new JMenuItem("View game rules");
        m2.add(showRulesButton);
        JMenuItem m77 = new JMenuItem("View past game stats");
        m3.add(m77);
        mb.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JButton newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
            newGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    new inGameFrame();
                    dispose();
                }
            });
        panel.add(newGameButton);

        panel.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(true);

    }




}
```

**EightOff.java:**

```
import javax.swing.*;



public class EightOff {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        inGameFrame obj = new inGameFrame();
    }
}

    class inGameFrame extends JFrame
    {
        public inGameFrame() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pack();
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);

        }


    }
```

Any tips would be wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: 1) You never add your components, especially the `JMenuBar` and the `JPanel` to your `JFrame`. The only thing you correctly add is the `JLabel` with the icon. So you will need to add at least `setJMenuBar(mb)` and `add(panel)`. 2) There is no need to call `setVisible(true)` on each individual component. Add all components to your `JFrame` and at the end call `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` only on the frame itself.

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks for the insightful comment, I really appreciate you.

Comment: No worries. The [Java Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) is usually a good place to start. You will find information on all basic topics regarding swing, which all include working examples for your reference.